# QtSerialPort example fails

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I am using Qt 5.1 and when my app (which worked using QextSerialPort in v4.8.4) failed to communicate, I tried the example in ...\5.1.1\Src\qtserialport\examples\serialport\terminal.   And that fails too.

I have a simple USB dongle that emulates a COM port.   If I use RealTerm, I can send AT commands to it and get back OK just fine.

But the terminal example that comes with Qt does not communicate with it.   I looked at an API snooper, and I am getting an unsuccessful return with error of "997:Overlapped I/O operation is in progress" for WaitCommEvent and WriteFile.

I am running it on Windows 7, and I copied the exe and DLLs over to a Windows 8 machine, and it failed to communicate as well (though I didn't do the API snooping there).

Anyone have any ideas what to try?   How can the unmodified example app just plain fail?  I am befuddled.

Comment: Does it also fail on Linux with 5.1.1? Have you tried the csyncreader/writer from git or 5.2?

Comment: Also, could you please post a simple application that does not work for you? Alternatively, you can run this example which should build against 5.1.1: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/d9725b249de5a2a6bb45e4f4e1a1b316d91ed102:examples/serialport/cwritersync/main.cpp Then, please paste the output.

Comment: I was thinking to try it on linux as well, but I didn't get a chance yet.  I will do that when I get home tonight where I am running Linux.

Comment: OK, sure. In the meantime, you can try the csyncwriter example. Let me know if that works. If not, please paste the output from the console. You need to feed that command line example from stdin on Windows and that will be written to the port.

Comment: I thought the simplest example would be the one I first mentioned, namely https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/d9725b249de5a2a6bb45e4f4e1a1b316d91ed102:examples/serialport/terminal

Comment: no, that is overcomplicated IMO for simple cases like this. Even for more complex cases, I will eventually write a simpler than that in QML soon. :-)

Comment: if the csyncwriter works, then try the casyncwriter.

Comment: csyncwriter failed in the same way.   I made a screen capture of the program output as well as the API snooper at http://home.beccue.com/qtserialport-problem.jpg   The output does have an error about flow control (Unexpected flow control settings).  So maybe it's related to that?

Comment: so you are claiming the message you tried to send was not received?

Comment: It's hard to know if the hardware received it or not without reading the port.  This is why I chose "terminal" as the sample.  But the API snooper showed the same exact return status as the terminal app that failed to read any bytes.  But I really don't know if the data is reaching the device or not. Or if it is reading from the device that is the problem.

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand your scenario. You should know if the device recives the characters because if it does, it works as you expect it to work!

Comment: The way the device works is this. If I send it AT\r  then it sends back OK\r\n       And I never see the response of OK, so I don't know if it never received the AT or if it was unable to send me the OK.

Comment: well you could use a loopback for TX/RX on your dongle to see you get AT back as the first step of debugging... let me know the result of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  I really appreciate it.  I have now seen the "terminal" app work.   As you suggested I hooked up a different serial device that has loopback capabilities.  So I am at least headed the right direction and should be able to debug this now I can see an example working.  The funny thing is that WriteFile API calls that work return FALSE and a 997 error, even as user3074135 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal example should work. You can track the issue down by first getting the [cwritersync](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/d9725b249de5a2a6bb45e4f4e1a1b316d91ed102%3aexamples/serialport/cwritersync/main.cpp) example work.

If that is not working, try to make a loopback between the RX and TX lines which are usually the 2nd and 3rd pins of your 9-pins serial port.

Having got that working, you can go further, and try to use the [cwriterasync](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/source/d9725b249de5a2a6bb45e4f4e1a1b316d91ed102%3aexamples/serialport/cwriterasync/serialportwriter.cpp) example which is a step closer to what the terminal example is using.

Once, that is working, you can realize what you would have done wrong with the terminal example. It might still be a QtSerialPort bug, but in that case we need all your details about the hardware environment.

Also, please make sure in that case whether or not the terminal example works fine for instance on Unices.

Comment: I found the problem!! :-)     My code all works when I add `QApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);` in front of `QByteArray myData = testPort.readAll();`  Then the readAll returns what I expect.  I guess I am using synchronous reading wrong somehow, or there is a bug in it.

Comment: @David: interesting; thanks for the follow-up! I am glad it works now. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Please try the Qt 5.2 with the available QtSerialPort module (or try to build a last version of the QtSerialPort from git).

> I have a simple USB dongle...

What is dongle model? VID/PID?

> ...return with error of "997:Overlapped I/O operation is in progress..

it is not an error.

Comment: The terminal example should work with 5.1, too.

Comment: And actually, that is an error (bug), which we eventually need to fix. I think such posts like this need to go as comment first since it does not actually address the concern in the question.

Comment: The dongle is a BT dongle with vid/pid (which is properly detected by the sample app) of 403/6001

Comment: Is used the MS bluetooth stack or BlueSoleil or other software?

Comment: I believe it is the FTDI driver since that's what the Driver tab on the Properties page of the USB Serial Port (COM10) says under Driver Provider.